# Error: StateProvider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have this error as **Error: StateProvider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null**. And it is coming due to this section.
I am working on my project and using **react** and **redux**.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { StateProvider } from './StateProvider';
import { reducer, initialState } from './reducer';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
       <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

**My App compo is like this**

```js
import './App.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
       <div className="app">
         <Header/>
         <Switch>
            <Router path="/checkout">
               <Checkout/>
            </Router>
            <Router path="/">
               <Home/>
            </Router>
         </Switch>
       </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**And my reducer is like this**

```js
const initialState = {
    basket : [],
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
     
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD_TO_BASKET": 
          return{
            ...state,
              basket: [...state, action.item],
          };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export  {reducer, initialState};
```

---

A**nd my stateProvider is like this**

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";


export const StateContext = createContext();


export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => {
     
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
};


export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: Hello! As the error says, missing `return` in `StateProvider`. The function does not have the return statement.

Comment: Can you please tell me at which line I need to put return satement, because I tried using return statement but it was saying error as Unexpected token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the return statement here:

```
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => {
     
    return (<StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>)
};
```

Comment: Ya its working. Thank You for giving solution.